# std::vector member variable EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, exc-bad-access

My class `load_game_state` (definition) has a member variable `_saveGameItems` of type `vector<shared_ptr<SaveGameState>>` and is never initialised (which it shouldn't need to).

Upon trying to use `push_back()` or `emplace_back()` on this vector I get a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error. I do not understand why I can not add objects to this vector.

The `SaveGameData` objects that populate the vector `saves`. Get constructed correctly, each object contains three strings (namely a path, a description an a timestamp (which is actually just a string)).

My code:

**load_game_state.cpp**

```
vector<std::string> LoadGameState::getFilePathsOfSaveGames() {
JSONParser jp = JSONParser {};
vector<string> paths = get_all("assets/saves/", ".json");
vector<shared_ptr<SaveGameItem>> saves;



// Extract data
for(auto path : paths) {
    json tmpData = jp.getSaveGame(path);
    saves.emplace_back(make_shared<SaveGameItem>(SaveGameItem(path, tmpData.at("saveTime"), tmpData.at("name"))));
}

_saveGameItems = saves;

}
```

**load_game_state.h**

```
#ifndef RISKY_LOAD_GAME_STATE_H
#define RISKY_LOAD_GAME_STATE_H

#include "state.h"
#include "../risky.h"
#include "../scenes/load_game_scene.h"
#include "load_game_controller.h"
#include "../models/SaveGameItem.h"

#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

namespace fs = ::boost::filesystem;

class LoadGameState : public State, public LoadGameController {

public:
    LoadGameState(Risky& context, GameEngine& engine, StateManager* stateManager);
    BaseScene& getScene() override;
    void doQuit() override;
    void handleInput() override;
    void update() override;
    ~LoadGameState();

    vector<string> get_all(const boost::filesystem::path& root, const string& ext);

    const vector<shared_ptr<SaveGameItem>> &get_saveGameItems() const;

    void set_saveGameItems(const vector<shared_ptr<SaveGameItem>> &_saveGameItems);

    // TODO get file paths of all JSON files
    vector<std::string> getFilePathsOfSaveGames() override;

    // TODO parse into SaveGameItem objects

    // TODO display these objects


private:
    LoadGameScene _scene;
    Risky& _riskyRef;
    GameEngine& _engineRef;

    // SaveGameItems
    vector<shared_ptr<SaveGameItem>> _saveGameItems;
};

#endif //RISKY_LOAD_GAME_STATE_H
```

**SaveGameItem** looks as follows:

```
class SaveGameItem {
    public:
    SaveGameItem();

    SaveGameItem(std::string filePath, std::string timestamp, std::string name);

    const std::string &get_filePath() const;

    void set_filePath(const std::string &_filePath);

    const std::string &get_timestamp() const;

    void set_timestamp(const std::string &_timestamp);

    const std::string &get_name() const;

    void set_name(const std::string &_name);

    ~SaveGameItem();

private:
    std::string _filePath;
    std::string _timestamp;
    std::string _name;
};
```

Comment: Please provide [mcve] instead of descriptions of code.

Comment: What is `SaveGameItem`? What does `tmpData.at("saveTime")` return? Why are you sure that the `emplace_back` is the cause of the crash? This is not a real [mcve] as we cannot compile it on our own (and there's too much missing information to find the real issue)

Comment: I have added additional information @AlgirdasPreidžius

Comment: Every function that gets called on `_saveGameItems` results in a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error @UnholySheep

Comment: You aren't calling any function on `_saveGameItems` (at least not in the code you have shown), the only actual use of it is `_saveGameItems = saves;`

Comment: Oops, I meant that any use of operators (in this case the assignment operator) or function calls on `_saveGameItems` results in that error. @UnholySheep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. `_saveGameItems` hadn't been initialised yet as the constructor of the class that called `getFilePathsOfSaveGames()` was called in the constructor of another class preventing `_saveGameItems` from being initialised.